# Jekyll + redcarpet line numbers

Tags: jekyll, github-flavored-markdown, redcarpet

I set up a Jekyll blog and I have the following config for syntax highlighting.

```
markdown: redcarpet
highlighter: pygments
```

This allows me to add syntax highlighting like this:

````
```javascript
function blah(){

}
```
````

Is there any way to keep this format but add line numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Out of the box Jekyll code highlight](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#line-numbers) :

```
{% highlight ruby linenos %}
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

And no need to highlight with javascript. Just add `pygments` css.

Comment: Yes, we can do it this way. I asked if we can use the backtick syntax do add line numbers, just like we can add linenos to this syntax.

Comment: So... I wrote a macro that turns ``` + tab into what you wrote above.

Comment: Just let us know how you did this ! It can help.

Comment: Is there a way to have linenumbers start at a certain value? ( :44, :45, :46 …)